# My internet connection just got really slow - How can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: windows-7, router, speed, adsl, internet-connection

A few days ago my connection became really slow. I have DSL which should be 3mb down and 768k up. I'm lucky if I get 768k down and 200k up. It sucks. I called my ISP, Verizon and they did some sort of line test and told me the problem was on my end. I rebooted my modem several times, like they told me. I'm not really sure why I even bothered calling them, the guy on the other end was just reading stuff out of a notebook - pretty useless.

So, I checked my network traffic in windows resource monitor, and there doesn't seem to be anything there hogging the bandwidth.

What else could be slowing my connection down on my PC? on my router? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up swapping out Ethernet cable between computer and router - much faster now! Kind of weird that it crapped out all of a sudden, but seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an open WiFi connection then someone else could be "borrowing" it.

Otherwise the ISP's guess is as good as mine. The best option would be to have them come out and trouble shoot it. They will have a *much* better idea about the current setup, likely culprits, things to try.

Comment: WiFi is secured so I don't think that's the issue. Verizon isn't being too friendly, so not sure how that will work out.